# Python script that automates SSH-ing into server, telnets into printer via port 9100, runs two commands and rinses and repeats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My goal is to remote into an array of networked devices and change a timeout setting to "10". I believe this can be automated via Python.

Can someone help me get started with a python script that does the following workflow:

1. SSH into server that is local to the networked devices in question.
2. Telnet into networked devices on 9100 port `telnet <ip address> 9100`.
3. Run command `getvar timeout value`
4. Expect output value of `"10"`.
5. If expected output value isn't `"10"`, run command `setvar timeout value 10`
6. Run command `getvar timeout value` again.
7. If expected output value continues to not be `"10"`, rinse and repeat steps 5-7.
8. If expected output value is `"10"`, log out of networked device.
9. Move onto next IP address of next networked device in array and repeat steps 1-9.

Comment: You might want to look into using something like Ansible instead if this isn't the only thing you're gonna do on all these machines: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to request code - you should help yourself by first *trying* to write some code to solve your problem: you will learn far more by trying - and you never know, you might succeed - than if someone in need of reputation points gifts you some code.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.fabfile.org/ - it allows you to python script up connections to remote servers via ssh and to do all sorts of stuff.